# "upgrade" the new [rad750] tag to something like [radiation-hardening] or "downgrade" it to the cornfield, or combine with [shielding], or...?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

- The new question [Are there already spacecraft equipped with RAD5500 processors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/60304/12102) has a [rad750](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rad750) tag
- this is currently the only question where this tag can be found
- this question isn't even about the RAD750
- there currently isn't a tag for the radiation hardening of electronics or other components. **note:** there's some overlap with shielding, but they're not the same thing.
- There are 19 questions with ["radiation hardened"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22radiation+hardened%22+is%3Aquestion), five with ["radiation hardening"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22radiation+hardening%22+is%3Aquestion) and two with ["radiation resistant"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22radiation+resistant%22+is%3Aquestion). There may be some overlap there.

Options might include

1. upgrading the tag to [radiation-hardening]
2. downgrade the tag by sending it to the [cornfield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SdFpBKENJfk) (i.e. out of reach or access; "disappear" it)
3. combine it somehow with [shielding](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shielding) even though it is substantially distinct from that.
4. something else?

A typical question that could also be a home for the possible tag is [What makes Insight's RAD750 processor so radiation resistant? (compared to 1998 iMac's PowerPC 750)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50470/12102)

Comment: Shielding feels almost entirely inappropriate to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, I think get rid of [rad-750](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rad-750) and tag the question with [radiation-hardening](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radiation-hardening).

Comment: nice, thank you!